# Jquery mobile last Grid item not vertically aligned

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am a newbie, trying to create a simple grid layout using jquery mobile version 1.4.5 learning from [jquerymobile demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids/)  . Either it is 2 or more column grid layout, last div element never align vertically with others unless it's width is reduced.
 Here is my 2 column grid layout code

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a"><textarea></textarea></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><textarea></textarea></div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j43xh6k3/ . 
The second div will align vertically after resizing it's size to around 40% from 50%. This problem exist also with more than 2 column grid layout. After searching stackoverflow I came across this http://jsfiddle.net/Ltx2md34/1/ , which uses jquery mobile version 1.4.2. and is what I want to achieve. So, I tried changing version of Jquery mobile in my code but the problem didn't solve.Please help me understand where I have done wrong 
*Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got rid of the problem by removing the white space and carriage return between the two enclosed divs:

First I did this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><textarea></textarea></div><div class="ui-block-b"><textarea></textarea></div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
```

And then re-indented back to:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><textarea></textarea></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><textarea></textarea></div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
```

Maybe there's a hidden character in their somewhere messing things up.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I have been trying to figure out what is wrong for so long, never thought there could be hidden character like this.

Comment: The problem is when you copy some text from http://demos.jquerymobile.com, some wired chars appear from "space" formatting. Seen them using a HEX VIEW.